# Creating a list of lambda functions with parameters fixed at creation

Tags: python, lambda

I need to create a list of lambda functions, that call another function with parameters, whose value should be contained in the function.

Instead of containing a fixed value of a parameter, the lambdas seem to contain a link to it

```
b = [lambda n: n*x for x in [1,2,3,4]]
>>> for func in b:
...     print(func(2))
... 
8
8
8
8
```

expected output:

```
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: what's your question mate ?

Comment: The question was how can I avoid that behavior, and probably creating a function that takes parameters and returns a lambda function is a solution. Sorry for creating duplicates.